# How much space is considered standard between consecutive "「" and "『"s?

Tags: orthography, quotes, typesetting

In a text such as `「『捨てる 』技術」` how much space is expected between the first two characters in typography,  if any?

Comment: This is a very tough question because each company has different house rule. For starters, you can find 14 different presets of InDesign [here](http://www.bookhouse.jp/default/spacing01.html). This page also shows how `「『』」` is typically typeset.

Comment: I am not aware that one can use "consequent" (following *logically*) in the sense of "consecutive" (following positionally), but I am not a native speaker and the etymology fits nicely enough. I assume that is what you mean?

Comment: I found a nice explanation in English here: [Requirements for Japanese Text Layout (W3C Working Group Note): 3.1.4 Positioning of Consecutive Opening Brackets, Closing Brackets, Commas, Full Stops and Middle Dots](https://www.w3.org/TR/jlreq/#positioning_of_consecutive_opening_brackets_closing_brackets_comma_full_stops_and_middle_dots)

Comment: @Peter Yes you're correct, I should have used the word "consecutive", corrected the title.

Comment: @naruto Thank you, those are really helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When there is no additional constraints imposed by [kinsoku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_breaking_rules_in_East_Asian_languages#Line_breaking_rules_in_Japanese_text_(Kinsoku_Shori)) or full-justification, this is how `「『捨てる』技術」` is typically typeset (produced by Adobe InDesign 2020, font: 小塚明朝 Pr6N, all characters are zenkaku):

[image: InDesign screenshot]

That is, brackets are rendered like zenkaku or hankaku depending on the surrounding characters/symbols. In other words, the built-in space is usually 50% but it sometimes becomes 0% (or somewhere between 0% and 50% when kinsoku is relevant).

Note that this is for main body text. In posters, book covers and such, you may want even narrower spaces, especially between `』` and `技`. Also note that detailed rules vary from publisher to publisher. The InDesign's settings dialog looks like [this](http://www.bookhouse.jp/default/spacing02.html).

Answer (score 1):

Typically in Japanese, you don't really encounter spaces, unless you are parsing for someone who is struggling to read.  The only exception is romaji, which is typically only used by foreign Japanese learners.

The 「」 and  『』 characters, along with a few others like square brackets, round brackets and parenthesis, have a space built into the character.  This is because the actual character is half-width, meaning it doesn't take a full square like other Japanese characters.  Because of this, when typing in full-width modes, you'll notice that the characters have a built in space wither before or after the character in question.  The same also applies to the sentence final '。' character, as you can see by the single quote positioning.

So to the best of my knowledge the answer is that you usually won't use spaces, as they are typically built into the system.  There may be stylistic reasons to add spaces, but it isn't required by the language.

Comment: If you want to remove the built-in spaces for stylistic reasons, you can do so by typing in half-width Japanese, which can be adjusted by the IME that you are using.

Comment: I am aware. What I'm looking for is the usual amount of that 'built-in" space, since I'm trying to define custom quotes for LaTex.

Comment: @user36529 If the document in interest is mainly in Japanese, I'd suggest using engines (uplatex etc.) or packages ([BXjscls class files](https://texwiki.texjp.org/?BXjscls), [luatex-ja](https://ja.osdn.net/projects/luatex-ja/wiki/FrontPage%28en%29), etc.) and leave the styles to their default. If you're a TeXnician and feel comfortable reading Japanese, reading the implementation and/or consulting to the Japanese TeX community (e.g. [forum](https://oku.edu.mie-u.ac.jp/tex/)) might help, too.

Comment: @Yosh, thanks, I'm already using lualatexja, although packages like biblatex rely on csquotes to define quotation marks for different languages, and unfortunately there is no support for Japanese, and one has to define it manually, which has a "space" parameter for when a font fails to provide any space. So I was looking for such a value, and I doubted anyone without knowledge of Japanese would be able to help, thus asking it here.